# Merge outputs (created in a loop) to one layer

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I am looping through some functions and get a result(s) on every loop. So i get a layer for every loop i am going through.
How do i reduce that to a single layer?

My code looks like that:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterNumber
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterMapLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
import processing


class example(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Test', 'test', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(11, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        for x in range(1, 10):

...functions etc...

                # LastFunction
                alg_params = {
                    'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
                    'FIELD_NAME': 'fieldname',
                    'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
                    'FIELD_TYPE': 1, 
                    'FORMULA': 'array_find(array_agg($id, group_by:=\"cm_id\", order_by:=\"cost\"), $id) +1',
                    'INPUT': outputs['OtherFunction']['OUTPUT'],
                    'OUTPUT': parameters['Test']
                }
                outputs['LastFunction'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
                results['Test'] = outputs['LastFunction']['OUTPUT']
                
        
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'example'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'example'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return example()
```

I tried to work with

`results.append(outputs['LastFunction']['OUTPUT'])`

`results['Test'].append(outputs['LastFunction']['OUTPUT'])`

`results += outputs['LastFunction']['OUTPUT']`

`results['Test'] += outputs['LastFunction']['OUTPUT']`

and tried to turn the results into an array `results = []` but then i get an error message at the output of results (return results).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I added an array resultlayers

```
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(11, model_feedback)
        resultlayer = []
        results = {}
        outputs = {}
```

At the end of the loop (inside the loop!) I am appending the result to this array

```
                # LastFunction
                alg_params = {
                    'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
                    'FIELD_NAME': 'fieldname',
                    'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
                    'FIELD_TYPE': 1,  # Ganze Zahl
                    'FORMULA': 'array_find(array_agg($id, group_by:=\"cm_id\", order_by:=\"cost\"), $id) +1',
                    'INPUT': outputs['OtherFunction']['OUTPUT'],
                    'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
                }
                outputs['LastFunction'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
                resultlayer.append(context.takeResultLayer(outputs['LastFunction']['OUTPUT']))
```

Before returning the results i use the native function mergevectorlayers:

```
        # merge vectorlayers
        alg_params = {
            'CRS': 'ProjectCrs',
            'LAYERS': resultlayer,
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Merged']
        }
        outputs['mergevectorlayers'] = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Merged'] = outputs['mergevectorlayers']['OUTPUT']
        
        return results
```

And now there is only one Outputlayer.